# Touch event not working on IOS with tel links

Tags: jquery, ios, events, tel

I'm trying to intercept a click on a  `tel` link on **IOS** like :

`<a href="tel:152354">Example</a>`

I've created a Fiddle here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Portekoi/yzg1eb96/4/

When I use my iPhone 6S, first link do not firing the alert. But the second link, yes.

I've try to add the CSS hack for IOS `cursor : pointer` but without success.

How can intercept the click on a `tel` href on IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me[image]

Check attached image

Comment: Yes and no : alert is firing BUT the phone do not propose to call the number. So no, it's nor working. Thanks